# How can I save sentences I wrote in the command section to a text file

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, bufferedreader

For a new program I want to save words that are written to the console to a text file. I am able to read the file, but not to save things to the file. I have prepared some code, in which I read the file, but I don't know how to save things to it.

I have tried to use the BufferedWriter but I wasn't able to use it right

```
import java.io.*;
public class main {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("/Test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        System.out.println(br.readLine());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failure!");
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use the BufferedWriter to save things to the file and read them, when the program is started again

Comment: I don't understand what is causing you problems here.  What do you want us to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will let you write to file

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        String inputLite = sc.nextLine();

        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("/Test.txt");
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            bufferedWriter.write(inputLite);

            fileWriter.close();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            System.out.println("Success!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failure");
        }


    }
```

Using Scanner class for getting input from console, then BufferedWritter to write into the file.

Comment: That doesn't work. When I write something to the console and press enter it is just printing Failure

Comment: Sorry, try this:

```try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            String inputLite = sc.nextLine();

            try(FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("Test.txt");
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)) {
                bufferedWriter.write(inputLite);

                System.out.println("Success");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Failure");

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }```